# Suitable data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, python-3.x

I need to create a data structure which will hold the information for various companies, with the following rules.

if  company A owns >50% of stock in company B, company A 'controls' company B.
if company B owns >50% of stock in company C, then B controls C, and A controls B and C.
if company A controls company B, C, and D, and combined, B,C and D'd shares in company E add up to >50%, then company A owns company E.

I have managed to do this fine, but the last part is messing me up. so far, my programs end up  in endless loops, or just dont work for the last part.

I realize this question may be a bit poorly made, but id appreciate even just a point in the right direction.

Comment: Show us what you have so far. We can't help you if we don't know what you've done.

Comment: Sounds like a tree. In each parent node, store the % ownership, and a pointer to the child node. Keep all the nodes with >50% ownership in one list and the others in another list. Doing a depth first search while going down the >50% list should reveal all the transitive ownerships.

Comment: There is a real opportunity for an endless loop here. If company A owns 51% of company B and Company B owns 51% of company A. Determining ownership may get messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_controlled(company, shares):
    # shares the company owns directly
    controls = set([company])       # avoid the recursion problem pointed out by @Justin
    owns     = defaultdict(float)
    owns.update(shares[company])

    # first level of controlled companies to look at
    add_control = set(k for k,v in owns.items() if v > 0.50)

    while add_control:
        # new level of controlled companies to look at next
        _add_control = set()

        for cpy in add_control:
            controls.add(cpy)
            for k,v in shares[cpy].items():
                owns[k] += v
                if owns[k] > 0.5 and k not in controls:
                    _add_control.add(k)
        add_control = _add_control

    return sorted(controls - set([company]))

def main():
    # Data structure: dict of dict of float
    #   shares['A']['B'] = 0.51     means    A owns 51% of B's shares
    shares = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))

    # Who owns what
    shares['A']['B'] = 0.60
    shares['A']['C'] = 0.55
    shares['A']['D'] = 0.41
    shares['C']['D'] = 0.10
    shares['B']['E'] = 0.20
    shares['C']['E'] = 0.20
    shares['D']['E'] = 0.20

    # See who A controls:
    controlled = find_controlled('A', shares)
    print('A controls {}'.format(','.join(controlled)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```